# Specific field values extraction with single value only

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

Need to extract customers msisdn (From) who have sent only one SMS (Received) and that too "STOP". Logs are below -

> 5/27/18 11:38:29.598 PM    [2018-27-05 23:38:29.598 UTC] INFO
> pool-1-thread-3 [receivedSmsFileLogger]  - Received = "JE S8 TELMA
> MALADE", From = "0765473387", Valid = "false" host =  Vapp01SN source
> = D:\MIP\Logs\SMSC\Cycle1\received_sms.log sourcetype =   MIP_Received_SMS
>
> 5/27/18 9:28:30.569 PM     [2018-27-05 21:28:30.569 UTC] INFO pool-1-thread-2 [receivedSmsFileLogger]  - Received =
> "''STOP''", From = "0765757431", Valid = "false" host =   Vapp01SN
> source =  D:\MIP\Logs\SMSC\Cycle1\received_sms.log sourcetype
> = MIP_Received_SMS
>
> 5/27/18 9:26:25.034 PM     [2018-27-05 21:26:25.034 UTC] INFO pool-1-thread-1 [receivedSmsFileLogger]  - Received =
> "1OUI", From = "0765757431", Valid = "false" host =   Vapp01SN source
> = D:\MIP\Logs\SMSC\Cycle1\received_sms.log sourcetype =   MIP_Received_SMS
>
> 5/27/18 9:06:36.889 PM     [2018-27-05 21:06:36.889 UTC] INFO pool-1-thread-3 [receivedSmsFileLogger]  - Received =
> "STOP", From = "0766108902", Valid = "true" host =    Vapp01SN source
> = D:\MIP\Logs\SMSC\Cycle1\received_sms.log sourcetype =   MIP_Received_SMS

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
index=foo sourcetype=bar 
| rex "From\s*=\s*\\"(?<msisdn>\d+)" 
| rex "Received\s*=\s*\\"(?<msg>[^\\"]+)" 
| stats count(msg) as msgCount values(msg) as Msgs by msisdn 
| where msgCount=1 AND (mvindex(0,Msgs)=="STOP")
```